# Sejuani vs Leona Support

Tags: league-of-legends

Yesterday, I decided to mix things up a bit in teambuilder and try an irregular support.
I decided on Sejuani since she has a little bit of CC (Q and Slows and after Lv6 Ultimate), I thought she'd be able to peel moderately while still dishing out damage.

Pros:

- Can deal more damage than Leona
- At Lv6 She can shutdown hyper carries that try to go after your ADC or other important targets.
- Ultimate's stun is more reliable as it is slightly faster to stun and it slows just like Leona's ultimate.

Cons:

- Not quite as tanky as Leona (negligible in my opinion, due to Sej Passive).
- Engaging is slightly more difficult as Sej's Q is shorter range than Leona's E.
- Only one stun (Not huge since Sej's Q knocks up enemies).

My Sej Build (so far):

I start with Relic and just play Passive Aggressive. I avoid taking unnecessary damage until I feel we have an opening then I go in. Fights before Lv.6 haven't gone terribly well, but not awful either. Once I hit Lv.6 it becomes an easy kill every 2 minutes or so. I've even stunned 4/5 enemies and slowed the 5th with Sej ult (something I've never even come close to doing with Leona).

Relic -> Sightstone -> Iceborn Gauntlet -> Randiuns -> Situational items such as MR or Rylai's.

I feel I did really well as Support Sej but obviously this was only against a couple of enemies. Once against Lux/Caitlyn and another against Thresh/Caitlyn. We won both matches, however, I can't help but feel this was solely because both teams had a Yi both games and all I had to do was Ult their Yi and ours would destroy their team.

**Question(s)**: Is it agreeable that Sejuani can support? Are there other Pros/Cons I have missed? Things to keep in mind? Do you think Sej would be viable without using a hyper-carry like Yi?

Comment: I think if you can master her as a support, she'll be great, like I saw, very rarely, Darius as support that the player knew how and when to engage that the bot lane (once I was there) had a hard time dealing with that unusual support. Just to say that most champs can end up being a great support, just have to know how to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I have no worries that I'll eventually master her. I just don't want to try and master a lane that might result as a sub-par lane or a lane that's only winning because the enemy has little-to-no experience against. Kind of like Blitzcrank, only bad players lose to him in lane. :/

Comment: If you master her as support, you should not have a weak lane. People will not be well prepared to face a support Sej, that will give you a edge if you play her right. Unusual support can wreck a good duo bot since they won't know till too late how to handle that support.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Unusual supports wrecking only really works in b/silver where people don't know what their abilities and weaknesses are

Comment: @Shelby115 pros play blitzcrank in lcs, i would hardly say only bad players lose to him in lane, he is very strong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can Support? Sure. Every champion can support. You can also play every champion on full AD and most of them also on full AP. The main question is: **Is sejuani better than other supporters?**

Now I agree with most of the points you listed in the pro vs con in comparison to Leone except for one.

Sejuani doesn't deal more damage than Leona. While yes she does more damage on her own, one of the main reasons why leona is so strong is her passive which will get triggered by different friendly damage spells.

Let's take a look at the more popular supporters in the current meta (except for Leona, your points are right if we don't look at the damage factor)

**Thresh**

- Huge utility with lantern, Aggressive and defensive
- Well placed hook can change a Lane/Game
- His E provides a strong offensive and defensive mechanic
- Can harass with autoattacks

**Nami**

- Great sustain
- AOE CC Chain
- Can Buff Damage, Movementspeed and On-Hit slow
- Can harass with autoattacks

**Morgana**

- Longest Hard-CC in the game (3 seconds, 5 seconds if chained)
- Can negate stuns
- Damage dealer in late game

Now as you can see: The things Sejuani is lacking are Long CC chains, Carry Protection, Damage and Utility. If one of these things were added or improved, I'm sure she would make for a great support but currently there are far more viable choices.

Now as I said, this doesn't mean she is completely unviable as a supporter, who knows maybe you can get to challenger by playing a mastered Support Sejuani but remember: Winning games, no matter what rating you're at, is possible with every champion but usually adapting to the Tier lists and Meta is a lot easier.

Comment: I completely agree. I did forget about the Leona passive, that was a good point. I think I'll play some more Sej support just to see how it goes, I believe she has potential but I can also see people complaining a lot about her. I might keep her as a support for matches where we already have decent peal for the adc and they have a hyper carry. Seems to be her point of excellence.

Comment: the problem is see with sejuani is, that you can engage to kill the enemies, but its hard to protect your ADC when the enemies engage on you without getting killed on your own.

Answer (score 2):

I play Sejuani support as well and I love her! I do agree with other people that Sejuani is not as tanky as Leona. However, the main reason that I play her is that her scaling as a support is better than Leona late game. Her W scales with health (max. health as patch 4.21) so building lots of health (even building Fountain and Ruby Stone adds 900 health) will make Sejuani more tanky and deals more DoT.

I agree that with a single target, Sejuani does not have as much CC compared to Leona. However, in teamfight, Sejuani's CC are indeed superior because of all of her CC are AOE and so you can disable more champions in the team fight compared to Leona. I love playing Sejuani because I like to have support that scales well to late game and have AOE CC.

Not saying that Sejuani is better than Leona or anything but I do think that Sejuani support is viable. Those who seeks to have early strong laning phase might not like Sejuani. It is not always about the early game.

Comment: Fair enough answer but I would still argue that Leona scales with HP as well since she already has built in resistances.  She doesn't scale in damage that way but does in survivability.  +1 though for being a new user.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest con of sej support is that most (all?) of her abilities do AoE damage. This is an issue because it mucks with your marksman's ability to farm.

All of your abilities also somewhat expose you to poke if you try to harass. And there are better options to deal with master yi. (yi is a poor example for sej cause he can avoid a lot of her slowing abilities).

Others issues include she has little utility, no protective(others) abilities, and doesn't fill the tanky support role well early.

Sej will most likely not see a surge in support play anytime soon, and her abilities are much better suited for other roles.

Comment: I'd have to disagree with your first two comments. I mean the AoE *can* be a problem, but that's easily avoidable. Secondly, Yi can't avoid stun and knock up. I always wait till he Qs onto a teammate, stun him on return. Then when he goes to meditate I instantly Q him to prevent living, as long as I have a single teammate doing damage to him, going dead before he can do anything. I do agree with the lack of utility. However, Leona doesn't have much more utility than Sej. Sej's Q isn't quite comparable to Leona's but I feel Sej's Ultimate makes up for that.

Comment: @Shelby115 So you'd prefer playing a support that has no abilities they can use? :P also I was speaking of highlander not alpha strike. Either way there are much better supports for dealing with yi(alistar, janna, nami, morg, thresh,to name a few)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from Leona's passive, she also has two forms of hard CC in lane at level 2 (E and Q), where Sej  only has 1! This is super important in early engagements, especially from levels 2-5 when a lot of "who won bot lane" is decided. Sej passive and Leona W kind of cancel out in terms of defense, Leona gets more tankiness but Sej gets the small slow.

I can't say for sure that Sej would or wouldn't work, but I think getting to level 6 with a kill, and without dying, with Leona will be easier than with Sejuani.